# How to batch mint in Candy Machine V3?

Tags: nft, mint, candymachine

```
    **how to mint X NFTs in candy machine at once? here is the answer.**
    const txs = [];
    //you have to use for loop to push mint transactions to txs array. now I've used just 2.
    txs.push(
      await metaplex.candyMachines().builders().mint({
        candyMachine,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authorityAddress,
        })
    );

    txs.push(
      await metaplex.candyMachines().builders().mint({
        candyMachine,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authorityAddress,
        })
    );

      const block = await metaplex.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
      const txns = txs.map((builder) => {
        const builderTx = builder.setFeePayer(metaplex.identity());

        const dropSigners = [metaplex.identity(), ...builderTx.getSigners()];
        const { keypairs } = getSignerHistogram(dropSigners);
        const tx = builderTx.toTransaction({
          blockhash: block.blockhash,
          lastValidBlockHeight: block.lastValidBlockHeight,
        });

        if (keypairs.length > 0) {
          tx.partialSign(...keypairs);
        }
        return tx;
      });

      // make the connected wallet sign all transactions
      const signedTx = await metaplex.identity().signAllTransactions(txns);

      // send the signed transactions in batches
      const batchSize = 200; // sends 200 raw tx in parallel
      const batches = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < signedTx.length; i += batchSize) {
        batches.push(signedTx.slice(i, i + batchSize));
      }
      let signatures = [];
      for (const txs of batches) {
        const signature = await Promise.all(
          txs.map((tx) => metaplex.connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())),
        );
        signatures.push(signature);
      }

      // wait for confirmations in parallel batches
      let confirmations = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < signatures.length; i += 1) {
        await delay(1000); // add delay to avoid rate limiting
        const sigs = signatures[i];
        const confirmationBatch = await Promise.all(
          sigs.map((sig) => {
            return metaplex.rpc().confirmTransaction(sig, {
              blockhash: block.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: block.lastValidBlockHeight,
            });
          }),
        );
        confirmations.push(...confirmationBatch);
      }

      if (confirmations.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Transaction failed");
      }

      return signatures.flatMap((sig) => sig).map((signature) => ({ signature }));
```